# Example of boundary parallel surfaces with boundary

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

"boundary parallel annulus" always appears in books/papers on 3-manifold theory. I know a surface is called boundary parallel if there is an isotopy sending it onto a boundary component. But if a surface has boundary (e.g. an annulus), how can it be isotoped onto a boundary component of some 3-manifold? Does it mean that there is an isotopy rel boundary sending the surface onto its image? Can any one give any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A properly embedded annulus in a 3-manifold $M$ is boundary parallel if it can be isotoped rel boundary so that its image is entirely contained in a boundary component of the the 3-manifold. After the isotopy, the annulus will not comprise the entire boundary but will simply be a subset of a boundary component.

There aren't any particularly interesting examples of boundary parallel annuli, because by definition, they are simply subsets of a boundary component up to isotopy. Typically one is more interested by non-boundary parallel annuli, because their existence says something about the topology of a manifold.

Comment: Thanks! I thought a boundary parallel should be isotopic (in particular homeomorphic) to a boundary component. So is a knotted annulus in 3-ball an example of non-boundary parallel annulus?

Comment: When we discuss boundary parallel, we are only ever considering proper embeddings (i.e you need the boundary of the annulus to be mapped into the boundary of the manifold). I'm not sure what you are imagining, but every properly embedded annulus in the 3-ball is boundary parallel.

Comment: If you have an annulus where each boundary component lies on distinct boundary component of the manifold, then this is automatically not boundary parallel. You can also find non boundary parallel annuli in torus knot complements for example.

Comment: Let's start with a knotted interval in a 3-ball with two ends on the boundary of the 3-ball. Then the boundary of the tubler neighborhood of the interval is a properly embedded annulus. How can it be isotopic to the boundary of the 3-ball? I don't know how to imagine it.

Comment: Sorry, you're completely right; such an annulus in $B^3$ will not be boundary parallel.

Comment: I was secretly also assuming that we were taking our annulus to be incompressible, which of course we're not. This doesn't change the overall answer, but perhaps I should emphasize that it's really incompressible non-boundary parallel annuli that are important. Your argument generalizes to show that every 3-manifold with non-empty boundary contains a non-boundary parallel annulus.

Comment: One more question. You said every properly embedded incompressible annulus in 3-ball is boundary parallel. But it seems that such annuli don't exist in a 3-ball, since every properly embedded annulus cobounds a cylinder, and there is a compression disk in this cylinder.

Comment: Indeed you are once again correct. There no so such surfaces. In fact there are no incompressible surfaces at all in the 3-ball. So technically what I said was true: every incompressible annulus is boundary parallel, but since there aren't any, this is not a statement with any real content...